# Remix: Gas estimation errored...The transaction execution will likely fail

Tags: solidity, remix

This error seems to get fixed by resolving an obscure exception in one's code. I'm trying to invoke `Owner.transfer` in Remix, but being thrown the alert: `Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
The execution failed due to an exception. Reverted`.

The `Owner` contract just approves the sender for the specified amount, and invokes the `Depository` to transfer that amount to itself before updating `balances`.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

    import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

    contract Token is ERC20 {}

    contract Depository {
        mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

        function deposit(uint256 amount) external {
            require(amount > 0);

            Token token = Token(0xFab46E002BbF0b4509813474841E0716E6730136);
            require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount), "The deposit failed");
            balances[msg.sender] += amount;
        }
    }

    contract Owner {
        function transfer(uint256 amount) external {
            require(amount > 0);

            Token token = Token(0xFab46E002BbF0b4509813474841E0716E6730136);
            // 0xEa917... is the deployed Depository contract address
            token.approve(0xEa917F373afa9F7F4AdB31a01D4c91E763De6502, amount);

            Depository depository = Depository(0xEa917F373afa9F7F4AdB31a01D4c91E763De6502);
            depository.deposit(amount);

        }
    }
```

Is there a code issue? Can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Please explain the opening statement in your question - "This error seems to get fixed by resolving an obscure exception in one's code".

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems this error is usually caused by some gas-related bug specific to one's code.

Comment: This error is usually caused because one (Remix) in this case, executes `transaction.estimateGas` before executing `transaction.send`, in order to determine how much gas is required for the latter to complete successfully. However, if the actual function to be execute should revert for some reason, then it would revert in both cases (i.e., both in `estimateGas` and in `send`). In that sense, calling `estimateGas` serves also as a preliminary warning that your function will revert when you execute it (and the gas used prior to reverting will be lost).

Comment: You can understand that even from the error-message itself: `The transaction execution will likely fail` - likely, when you run it "for real" (i.e., not just for gas-estimation).

Comment: And BTW, approve/transferFrom flows typically fail for either one of two reasons: 1. Insufficient amount of tokens approved. 2. Insufficient amount of tokens available for transfer. In both cases, the revert occurs at a "safeSub" function. So I suggest that you start by looking into each one of these two reasons.

Comment: @goodvibration Oh man. Your explanation helps clear things up so much. My issue was that there weren't enough tokens in the `Owner` contract. You always seem to answer my questions, and I really can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied and deployed your code in remix.  I got it to work fine.

are you sure that you have tokens in the token contract, and in the right place?  I had to add a `mint` function in the `Token` constructor so I actually had some tokens.  Then, I needed to transfer some to the `Owner` contract - as this is where they actually need to be to subsequently be added to the Depository.

After that `Owner.transfer` worked and appeared to do the correct thing.

Comment: As I said in the (currently) last comment to the question - "2. Insufficient amount of tokens available for transfer".

Comment: Thanks a bunch @zakalwe and @goodvibration. That error only gets thrown when there aren't enough tokens in the `Owner` contract. Simple fix!