# Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below)

Tags: solidity

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the following code as it does deploy successfully on remix.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "./ERCI20.sol"; // ERC20 token interface
import "./SafeMath.sol"; // openzepplin safemath library

contract TimeBound is ERCI20 {

using SafeMath for uint256;
address public contractOwner;

mapping (address => uint256) private Balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private Allowances;

uint256 private _totalSupply;

string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals;

uint256 public releaseTime;

event releaseTimeSet(bool success, uint256 time);

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "TB9Token: Only owner allowed");
    _;
}
modifier TimeLock() {
    require(block.timestamp >= releaseTime, "TB9Token: Token is locked for certain Time");
    _;
}


constructor() public {
    name = "TimeBound Token";
    symbol = "TB9Token";
    decimals = 0;
    contractOwner = msg.sender;

    _totalSupply = 1000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

    Balances[contractOwner] = _totalSupply;

    emit Transfer(address(this), contractOwner, _totalSupply);
}

function totalSupply() external view override returns(uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}

function balanceOf(address account) external view override returns(uint256) {
    return Balances[account]; 
}

function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external override TimeLock() returns(bool) {
    address sender = msg.sender;

    require(sender != address(0), "TB9Token:should not transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "TB9Token:should not transfer to the zero address");
    require(Balances[sender] > amount);

    Balances[sender] = Balances[sender].sub(amount); 

    Balances[recipient] = Balances[recipient].add(amount);

    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    return true;
}
function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view override returns(uint256) {
    return Allowances[tokenOwner][spender];
} 
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external override returns(bool) {
    address tokenOwner = msg.sender;

    require(tokenOwner != address(0), "TB9Token: should not approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "TB9Token:should not approve to the zero address");

    Allowances[tokenOwner][spender] = amount;

    emit Approval(tokenOwner, spender, amount);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external override TimeLock() returns(bool) {
    address spender = msg.sender;
    uint256 Allowance = Allowances[sender][spender];

    require(sender != address(0), "TB9Token:should not transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "TB9Token:should not transfer to the zero address");
    require(Balances[sender] > amount, "TB9Token: transfer amount exceeds");
    require(Allowance > amount, "TB9Token: transfer amount exceeds allowance");

    Allowance = Allowance.sub(amount);

    Balances[recipient] = Balances[recipient].add(amount);

    Balances[sender] =Balances[sender].sub(amount); 

    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    Allowances[sender][spender] = Allowance;

    emit Approval(sender, spender, amount);

    return true;
}
function setReleaseTime(uint _releaseTime) public onlyOwner() returns(bool) {
    require(_releaseTime > block.timestamp, "TB9Token: releaseTime must be valid in the future");

    releaseTime = _releaseTime;

    emit releaseTimeSet(true, _releaseTime);

    return true;
}

}
```

i am deploying this code `timeBound` contract first on ropsten testnetwork using metamask. `timeBound` contract deploys successfully then i/m calling the following functions:

1. First i call the function `setReleaseTime` and put time in seconds unix time. `setReleaseTime` call successfully and i can see a transaction in my metamask.
2. Second i call `transfer` function and provide `recipent address` and `amount`.

as i call `transfer` function remix show me a pop up, this one `**Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
gas required exceeds allowance (8000029) or always failing transaction**`

[image]

may be i am calling wrong function first, please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Where are you deploying, a public testnet a private testnet? Likely one of the requires is failing.

Comment: See my comments to [this similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83391/16043).

Comment: BTW, with regards to `require(Balances[sender] > amount)`: 1. You probably want to use `>=` here. 2. Is the balance of the sender really larger than the amount that you are passing as input?

Comment: @Ismael i'm deploying it on ropsten with metamask and remix

Comment: @goodvibration i'll try. maybe i'm calling first the `releaseTime` function then i call `transfer` function, if the releaseTime function execute earlier and then transfer function executes, it might produce time error, but i gives Gas estimation error, which is unbelevieable

Comment: It DOESN'T give gas estimation error, please read my comments on that other question.